# Using Twig variable in AngularsJS

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2 with Twig and AngularJS. I need to pass Twig variable to angular's function. Currently I tried doing that like this: `ng-click="submitPost({{ channelName }})"` but when I `console.log` to check that variable I see it as undefined. How do I pass Twig variables to angular functions?

Comment: Use `ng-click="submitPost(channelName )"`

Comment: use {% verbatim %} http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html or modify angularjs brackets to another sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use temporary javascript variable to store the twig variable

```
var tmp = "{{ channelName }}";
ng-click="submitPost(tmp)"
```

Comment: In my opinion not really clean. If you need to pass many of those twig variables you have a bunch of temporary variables. In contrast of course a redefinition of the `$interpolateProvider` can be overhead if you only need to pass a few twig variables.

Comment: Using temporary vars is a quick fix, but you can still write something like `ng-click='submitPost("{{ channelName }}")'` ( please notice the quotes and double quotes )

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Twig with AngularJS you will most likly run into conflicts as you might know. One solution is to use Angulars `$interpolateProvider` to change the start and end interpolation tags like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

In this case Angular will use `{[{` and `}]}` to interpolate expressions. It might be a bit odd to type but you can chose whatever you like. However, this will solve the conflicts between Twig and Angular.